# Python Use User Defined String Class

Tags: python

I know how to override string class with:

```
class UserString:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Overridden String'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print UserString()
```

But how can i use this class instead of built-in `str` class without defining implicitly `UserString` class?. To be clear 
I want this:

```
>>> print "Boo boo!"
Overridden String
```

Comment: It's not possible. You have not "overridden string class", you have defined a class whose instances can be converted to strings. You can't change the type of string literals.

Comment: Do you want to use the class? Or are you simply interested on overriding `print`?

Comment: I am trying to found a new way -that would be integrate seamlessly- to uppercase special Turkish unicode characters. In other words, when a `MYSTRING.upper()` method triggerer, I want to trigger my own `upper()` method.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. You have not overridden string class.

You cannot override classes. You can override methods. What you have done is defined a class and only overridden its **str**() method.

But you can do something like this...

```
def overriden_print(x):
    print "Overriden in the past!"

from __future__ import print_function  # import after the definition of overriden_print

print = overriden_print

print("Hello")
```

Output:

> Overriden in the past!

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do what you want without hacking the python executable itself... after all, `str` is a built-in type, and the interpreter, when passed `'string'` type immediates, will always create built-in strings.

However... it *is* possible, using delegation, to do something like this. This is slightly modified from another stackoverflow recipe (which sadly, I did not include a link to in my code...), so if this is your code, please feel free to claim it :)

```
def returnthisclassfrom(specials):
  specialnames = ['__%s__' % s for s in specials.split()]
  def wrapit(cls, method):
    return lambda *a: cls(method(*a))
  def dowrap(cls):
    for n in specialnames:
      method = getattr(cls, n)
      setattr(cls, n, wrapit(cls, method))
    return cls
  return dowrap
```

Then you use it like this:

```
@returnthisclassfrom('add mul mod')
class UserString(str):
    pass

In [11]: first = UserString('first')

In [12]: print first
first

In [13]: type(first)
Out[13]: __main__.UserString

In [14]: second = first + 'second'

In [15]: print second
firstsecond

In [16]: type(second)
Out[16]: __main__.UserString
```

One downside of this is that `str` has no `radd` support, so `'string1' + UserString('string2')` will give a string, whereas `UserString('string1') + 'string2'` gives a UserString. Not sure if there is a way around that.

Maybe not helpful, but hopefully it puts you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks, this is not the exactly i am looking for but i liked it, because, it uses decorators. And your code looks like http://stackoverflow.com/a/1243045/1766716 :)

Comment: that's the one... thanks for finding that! (annotating in code now...)