# How to get back an overridden python built-in function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I was exploring a solution for the StackOverflow problem, [Python Use User Defined String Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884949/python-use-user-defined-string-class), I came with this strange python behavior.

```
def overriden_print(x):
    print "Overriden in the past!"

from __future__ import print_function

print = overriden_print

print("Hello World!")
```

Output:

> Overriden in the past!

Now, how can I get back the original `print` behavior in python interpreter?

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but I can't reproduce the behaviour in Python 2.7.18; instead I get: `SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file`. Same in 3.11 if I add parentheses on the first `print`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Just delete the override:

```
del print
```

This deletes the name from the `globals()` dictionary, letting search fall back to the built-ins.

You can always refer directly to the built-in via the [`__builtin__` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) as well:

```
import __builtin__

__builtin__.print('Printing with the original built-in')
```

In Python 3, the module has been renamed to [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html).

Comment: this doesn't work inside functions with parameter names that match built-in names?  `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'range' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @endolith: parameters are *local* names. I'm not sure what you are trying to do there; you cannot use a name both as a local and a global, so once you use `range` as a parameter you cannot use `del` on it to get the global again.