# How can I call a built-in function, if the function is already overrided in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Now I just tried to test if I can call built-in function inside overrided function in Python3, as follows:

```py
def print(val=0):
    print("TEST")  # How can I call the original `print()` here to avoid RecursionError


print(10)
```

But the following error thrown. It makes sense.

```py
>>> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I am curious if there is ways to call an original built-in function inside its overrided function, such as `sys.__builtin__.print()` I guess.

Thank you.

Comment: While there are answers that answer your question, let us also mention: you should not do this! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get back an overridden python built-in function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885760/how-to-get-back-an-overridden-python-built-in-function)

Comment: @pippo1980 Thank you very much for the information. It was helpful but the answer is for Python2. However, I wanstd to know it for python3. I updated my question title to Python3.

Comment: @Tim-Erwin Sorry, I don't get it. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: It is bad practice to shadow the built in function names. Most IDE will give you a warning for this and most colleagues will hate you for it ;)

Comment: What I mean is, you should not override builtin functions in general.

Comment: @endive1783 Yes, that's right. I just wanted know how it works. My IDE PyCharm also show warning :)

Comment: @Tim-Erwin Thanks, I just wanted to know if it is possible or not in Python3. Not gonna use it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Builtins are available in a module called `builtins`. Makes sense!

```
import builtins

def print(val=0):
    builtins.print("TEST")  # How can I call the original `print()` here to avoid RecursionError

print(10)
```

Comment: woops i was too late

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `builtins` module to reference the built in `print`

```
import builtins
def print(val=0):
    builtins.print('TEST')
```

Answer (score 1):

I am posting same answer because I was beaten only by 2 minutes:

this solution in for python3 only python2 used `import __builtin__`

```
import builtins 

def print(val=0):
    builtins.print("TEST")  # How can I call the original `print()` here to avoid RecursionError


print(10)
```

output:

```
TEST
```

this works too:

```
def print(val=0):
    global print
    del print 
    print("TEST")  # How can I call the original `print()` here to avoid RecursionError


print(10)
```

see here for duplicated post

[How to get back an overridden python built-in function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885760/how-to-get-back-an-overridden-python-built-in-function)

Comment: Thank you for the additional information using `global` and `del`. Interesting!, Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import __builtin__

def print(val=0):    
     __builtin__.print('TEST')


print(10)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Make sure to test your code before posting. There is no `importable __builtin__` module, but there is a `__builtins__` module auto-imported for you.